# Unable access to pthread_mutex_t members in GDB

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, mutex, freebsd

I am unable to dump struct members value of pthread_mutex_t in gdb in order to detect a deadlock

```
(gdb) where
#0  boost::mutex::lock (this=0x7fffffffd980) at mutex.hpp:116
#1  0x000000000043454b in boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::lock (this=0x7fffffffd970) at lock_types.hpp:346
#2  0x0000000000434591 in unique_lock (this=0x7fffffffd970, m_=@0x7fffffffd980) at lock_types.hpp:124

(gdb) print m
$21 = 0x802418880
(gdb) print &m
$22 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0x7fffffffd980


GNU gdb 6.1.1 [FreeBSD]
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "amd64-marcel-freebsd".
```

source of testapp.cpp

```
boost::mutex cn_mutex;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(cn_mutex);
    mystruct st;
    st.id = 888;
    while(true)
    {
        usleep(1000 * 2000);
    }
    std::cout << "done \n";
    return 0;
```

Compile arguments:

```
   /usr/bin/c++ -g -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -g -pg CMakeFiles/testinterproc.dir/testapp.cpp.o -o testinterproc /usr/local/lib/libssl.so /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so /usr/local/lib/libexecinfo.so /usr/local/lib/liblog4cplus.so -lpthread /home/xgps_app/thirdparty/boostlib1_64_0/lib/libboost_iostre‌​ams.a /home/xgps_app/thirdparty/boostlib1_64_0/lib/libboost_system‌​.a /home/xgps_app/thirdparty/boostlib1_64_0lib/lib/boost_thread‌​.a /home/xgps_app/thirdparty/boostlib1_64_0 /home/xgps_app/thirdparty/boostlib1_64_0/lib/libboost_filesy‌​stem.a -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
```

OS 9.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE #1: amd64
Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: how did you compile your code?

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include the commands used.

Comment: Also note that the pthread types are [*opaque types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type). You're not supposed to know their members, or access them.

Comment: @Nikola please put additional details for your question in the question yourself.  You can click the "edit" button at the bottom of your question and add the details you put in the comment and then delete the comment.

Comment: There is no `m` in code you provided.

Comment: Sorry now i fixed and added command line to initial message. arrowd this is internal call in boost mutex

Comment: Still no `m` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

From the line

```
boost::mutex::lock (this=0x7fffffffd980) at mutex.hpp:116
```

we can deduce that the type of the object at address `0x7fffffffd980` is `boost::mutex`.

It then seems are casting `boost::mutex` to `pthread_mutex_t` which is a bad idea. (Alternatively, it could be that `gdb` is aware of the actual type of sub-object that  sits at offset `0` inside the `boost::mutex` type. Still, that field is private).

Even if you found the *correct* private member of `boost::mutex` that is of type `pthread_mutex_t`, then still you should not be relying on the implementation-specific values therein. It's undocumented for a reason (implementations may differ, it may change etc.)

**May I suggest using a thread testing (`-fsanitize=thread`, DRD or Helgrind) if you want/need to debug deadlocks.**